# Javascript Set not populating from large string Array

Tags: javascript, set

I have a large string array from ~6k string elements. I know sets work in my browser and are fine when testing on smaller arrays. When I try to convert the large array into a new Set, all it does is return an empty one.

My array is originally part of a nested one, although several methods of inputting it into the set have been tried. Some of these are:

```
var input = Bigger_array[1];

var input = [...Bigger_array[1]];

var dummy = Bigger_array[1];
var input = [...dummy];
```

Additionally different methods of creating the set have also been tried:

```
var s = new Set(input);

var s = new Set();
for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
     s.add(input[i]);
}
```

All to no avail:

```
set {}
```

As requested a working fiddle for smaller arrays:

```js
Bigger_array=[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]


var input = [...Bigger_array[1]];
var s = new Set();
for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
     s.add(input[j]);
}
console.log(s);


///the original method 
var input =Bigger_array[1]
var s = new Set(input);
console.log(s);

alert('viewing s in console presents correct values of set \n fiddle is being weird' )
//etc...
```

Comment: Spread operator fails if you have an array of huge sizes depending on your current session. Don't use spread with arrays larger than like 150K length.. In your second snippet you should say `s.add(input[j]);` though.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle showing your problem? Has the same code been tested with smaller arrays?

Comment: @Redu thanks for the heads up. I was only using that in the hope that it may have something to do with the referencing of the array (and thus creating a new one).

Comment: @andyroschy Question updated.

Comment: `var input = Bigger_array[1]; var s = new Set(input);` you try this on console and see that the Set is set. It's just that some JS engines won't `console.log()` the Set (and even the `Map`) object. I guess it's due to the constructor's `toString()` method or something. I had the [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925530/why-wouldnt-array-prototype-reduce-accept-a-map-object-as-an-initial-value) a while ago.

Comment: Output `s.size` to make sure you are not being mislead by the console behaviour.

Comment: @Redu that makes sense , and doing     `.size` or      `.forEach(funciton(d){console.log(d)})`  on the supposedly empty set object confirms this.  Can you type that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously some JS engines fail to `console.log()` the `Set` or the `Map` object properly and instead you just receive an empty looking object like `{}`. Don't be deceived. I believe it's about the `toString()` method of the Set constructor. More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36925530/4543207).

Answer (score 1):

Console can play tricks on you. It has its own methods for representing data, which are different from the JavaScript `toString` method. It can clip data, or even not display it at all. Other times it delays the output which can cause misleading output as well.

To confirm that your `set` is just fine, output its size:

```
console.log(s.size);
```

Or, you can just transform it back to an array:

```
console.log([...s]);
```